# Ошибка карты кода (bootstrap.js)

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, laravel, webpack

Собираю все js скрипты в один... Работаю в Laravel (использую дефолтный webpack и bootstrap.js). Собираю jQuery и сам bootstrap, затем в консоли (firefox) высвечивается

```
Ошибка карты кода: request failed with status 404
URL ресурса: http://laravel.test/js/app.js
URL карты кода: bootstrap.min.js.map
```

Но всё работает корректно, задевает сама эта надпись (в хроме её нету)

Развернул отладчик и увидел эту надпись (ошибка в самой библиотеке jQuery)

```
// Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
```

Как это может быть?

Comment: Уважаемый, куда добавили карту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился добавлением карт:

```
.sourceMaps()
```